# angular apply ng-hide on ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm trying to display an input field by double-click the name. This works fine! However, how do I switch back if my put-request is successful? I thought I just have to set $scope.edit to false but it does not work. (Made my first steps with angular today)

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="customer.selected"/>
        </label>
        <span ng-hide="edit" ng-dblclick="edit = true;">{{ customer.name }}</span>
        <label ng-show="edit">
            <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name" ng-keyup="editCustomer($index, customer, $event)"/>
        </label>,
        <small ng-bind="customer.created_at"></small>
        <button ng-click="deleteCustomer($index, customer)">-</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.editCustomer = function (index, customer, event) {
    // enter
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $http.put('customers/' + customer.id, customer).success(function () {
            // update customer.name binding
            $scope.edit = false;
        })
    } 
    // esc, do nothing and revert
    else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        $scope.edit = false;
    }
};
```

Or is there maybe a better solution for this approach?

Comment: This is a scoping issue.  An ngRepeat will create a child scope, but when you update $scope.edit = false, you are modifying the parent controller scope. To fix this put your ngController inside of your ngRepeat, or an alternative solution is to create a custom directive that defines a child/isolated scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem. By default `ng-repeat` creates a child or an isolated scope. So now you are trying to set a variable `edit` inside the scope of child scope created by `ng-repeat` but not in the scope of your actual controller.

But inside your controller, you are again trying to set its false value on parent scope not on child scope of `ng-repeat'. To fix this, you need to use an object for this variable.

This behavior is properly explained here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

So modify your HTML code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="customer.selected"/>
        </label>
        <span ng-show="!customer.edit" ng-dblclick="customer.edit = true;">{{customer.name}}</span>
        <label ng-show="customer.edit">
            <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name" ng-keyup="editCustomer($event)"/>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And your controller code to:

```
$scope.editCustomer = function (event) {
    var customer = this.customer;    // current customer can be directly accessed via this
    // enter
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $http.put('customers/' + customer.id, customer).success(function () {
            customer.edit = false;
        })
    } 
    // esc, do nothing and revert
    else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        customer.edit = false;
    }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
SA

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, works and seems to be logic to me.

Answer (score 0):

You must use both ng-hide and ng-show if you want to show and hide your input.
It's not logical but is the only way that it works in my controller, could be a bug.

```
<label ng-show="edit" ng-hide="edit-hide">
  <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name" ng-keyup="editCustomer($index, customer, $event)"/>
</label>


// Show control
$scope.edit = true;
$socpe.edit_hide = false;

// Hide control
$scope.edit = false;
$scope.edit_hide = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="customer.selected"/>
        </label>
        <span ng-show="!edit" ng-dblclick="edit = true;">{{ customer.name }}</span>
        <label ng-show="edit">
            <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name" ng-keyup="editCustomer($index, customer, $event)"/>
        </label>,
        <small ng-bind="customer.created_at"></small>
        <button ng-click="deleteCustomer($index, customer)">-</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.editCustomer = function (index, customer, event) {
    // enter
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $http.put('customers/' + customer.id, customer).success(function () {
            // update customer.name binding
            $scope.edit = false;
        })
    } 
    // esc, do nothing and revert
    else if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        // $scope.edit = false;
    }
};
```

Remember set default value $scope.edit = false on start of your controller.